# I need to create a new column that enumerates each row with respect to two other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to create a row that just enumerates each row value and resets anytime a threshold is met.

```
date           id    x   x2  x3   new_col
1/1/2018    1   0   x   x   1
1/2/2018    1   1   x   x   1
1/3/2018    1   0   x   x   2
1/4/2018    2   0   x   x   1
1/5/2018    2   0   x   x   2
1/6/2018    2   1   x   x   1
1/7/2018    2   0   x   x   1
1/8/2018    2   0   x   x   2
1/9/2018    3   0   x   x   1
1/10/2018   3   0   x   x   2
1/11/2018   3   0   x   x   3
1/12/2018   3   1   x   x   1
1/13/2018   3   0   x   x   1
1/14/2018   3   0   x   x   2
```

In this example, the new column need to start over anytime the id value changes OR anytime x1  == 1.

Comment: I am assuming you are using the Pandas library - Python does not have the concept of "columns" in the language. Some more information on what you have there, as Python code, would make easier for people to tackle your question.

Comment: a_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C']
b_list = ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a': a_list, 'col_b': b_list})
df = df.sort_values(by=['col_a'])
df

Comment: Why  there is 1 1 2 at the end ? should it be 1 2 3 ?

Comment: yes, i had a typo

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a `cumcount` problem

```
s=df.groupby([df.id,df.x.eq(1).cumsum()]).cumcount()+1
s
Out[410]: 
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     1
4     2
5     1
6     2
7     3
8     1
9     2
10    3
11    1
12    2
13    3
dtype: int64
df['New']=s
```